# Is there a current nvidia driver package from xorg-edgers?

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, ppa

Is there any current nvidia package (like `nvidia-current`) on xorg-edgers ppa for Ubuntu quantal?

I cant see any, i just found `nvidia-310` and `nvida-313`

Maybe another ppa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "-current" suffix refers to the compatibility of these drivers: it is for recent generations Nvidia cards. The nvidia-310 and nvidia-313 packages are targetted at the same generation nvidia cards, you can safely use them as replacement for nvidia-current. In fact, these packages provide the [package `nvidia-current` in the next Ubuntu version (Raring)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/nvidia-current).

If you really want to stick to the `nvidia-current` naming, you can try adding the ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates PPA, that still provides packages named `nvidia-current`.